# Search list in nodejs for Alexa skill

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to make an Alexa skill and I have gotten stuck while doing the backend code in AWS lambda. Basically I have a list of cities and if the user says one of the cities that is on the list to Alexa she is supposed to respond that, that city is valid. Below I have my list of cities and also the method which should be sorting through the list to find a match.

```
var data = [
    "San Mateo.",
    "San Francisco.",
    "Palo Alto.",
    "Redwood City.",
    "New York.",
    "Boston.",
    "Chicago.",
    "La Jolla.",
    "San Diego.",
    "San Carlos.",
    "San Bruno."
];

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};

var handlers = {
     'LaunchRequest': function () {
          this.emit('GetNewFactIntent');
     },

     'GetNewFactIntent': function () {
          var cityName = this.event.request.intent.slots.value;
          var factArr = data;

          for(var i = 0; i < factArr.length; i++){
              if(cityName.equals(factArr[i].value)){
                 this.emit(":tell", LYFT_IS_AVALIABLE);
              }
          }

          this.emit(":tell", LYFT_NOT_AVALIABLE);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So just a quick tip you didn't actually ask a question, you just pasted some code and said what you wanted to achieve, thats why somebody mean downvoted you.

So what you're after is Dot notation assuming the array you have there is the list you could do:

```
var data = [
    "San Mateo.",
    "San Francisco.",
    "Palo Alto.",
    "Redwood City.",
    "New York.",
    "Boston.",
    "Chicago.",
    "La Jolla.",
    "San Diego.",
    "San Carlos.",
    "San Bruno."
];

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};

var handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit('GetNewFactIntent');
    },

    'GetNewFactIntent': function () {
        var cityName = this.event.request.intent.slots.value;

        // this is like doing data['San Mateo.']
        if(typeof data[cityName] !== 'undefined'){

            this.emit(":tell", LYFT_IS_AVALIABLE);

        } else {
            this.emit(":tell", LYFT_NOT_AVALIABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use console.log(someVariable) in Lambda and examine the result in CloudWatch Logs - FYI Do your cities need the '.' at the end?